# Declare variable as one type then override with "new" to another type

Tags: c#

Apologies but couldn't think of a better way to describe this in the title. I'm also not a real developer so please excuse if I get my fields, variables, objects and methods confused.

Anyway I have some C# code that declares a private variable for my class, that's available throughout the entire class. Within the code however I actually decide what it is declared as. When I jump into another method some of the capabilities of the object/variable are not available due to the original declaration.

```
private NetPeer _peer; //initially declared here so it's visible in the entire class
....
public void Initialise()
{
  if("some arbitrary validation") 
  {
    _peer = new NetServer(_config); // This is now a NetServer object and not NetPeer, but works fine
  }
  else
  {
    _peer = new NetClient(_config); // This is now a NetClient object and not NetPeer, but works fine
  }
  _peer.Start(); // This works fine as NetClient or NetServer. The method is available to both
}

public void SendIt()
{
  _peer.SendToAll(_message); //Now this "SendToAll" is only available with the NetServer and not NetClient. At runtime this fails miserably as you would expect
}
```

So is there a way to declare the private "_peer" variable without defining it as NetServer or NetClient till later on, or do I need to just revisit the rest of my code and run with two separate variables.

It's not overtly relevant to the issue, but I'm using the Lidgren library which is where NetServer and NetClient come from. I suppose it could easily be any other class or method being referenced here.

I've also removed a lot of other logic and code to show this example.

**Edit: So I didn't realise asking a generic question would kick off such a battle. The code is working fine now and I've used the suggestion from Damien as that's the simplest for me to understand:
     ((NetServer)_peer).SendToAll(_message);

Thanks for everyone who offered positive help to my issue...

Comment: Are `NetServer` and `NetClient` related at all through inheritance? Do they share an interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
public void SendIt()
{
  var server = _peer as NetServer;
  if(_peer == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("SendIt called when we're not the server");
  server.SendToAll(_message);
}
```

And similarly in other methods that will only work for one type or the other. I could have left out the `if(_peer ...` line, but that would have left it as a `NullReferenceException` - I prefer to switch to a more meaningful exception type and at the same time be able to provide a hint on what, specifically, went wrong.

Similarly, I could have done a direct cast `((NetServer)_peer).SendToAll(...` but that would have thrown an `InvalidCastException` that would take more digging to diagnose the issue. I prefer to use [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and try to offer as rich a diagnostic experience as possible.

Comment: @radarbob - the question is only tagged `c#`, and the OP said "It's not overtly relevant to the issue, but I'm using the Lidgren library...". I took it to be a general C# question, not one that needs, necessarily, to use the library.

Comment: -1. <strike>Does not attempt to use the library</strike> Inappropriate as the library already has an appropriate OO solution

Comment: Although my issue is due to the use of the library it's more the way I was implementing it. I was aiming the question to be generic, as I'm sure I'll hit a similar issue further down the line. @Damien - Both the code and your direct cast suggestion worked a treat thanks. I did try to cast it originally, but I didn't have another set of brackets around the entire _peer text I just had (NetServer)_peer, which failed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an interface and have both  NetServer or NetClient derive from it

Comment: The question shows those classes both already have a common ancestor, NetPeer.

Comment: Not that I can see, In my opinion an interface is better then, say, declaring two different private variables.

Comment: -1. <strike>Does not attempt to use the library</strike> Inappropriate as the library already has an appropriate OO solution

Comment: @radarbob: huh? why would implementing an interface be inappropriate? DavidB is merely suggesting putting up a facade/container approach. I think it doesnt merit a -1. I'll +1 this to "even out" the points, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

You could add two wrapper properties for use inside your class:

```
private NetServer _peerServer
{
  get { return _peer as NetServer; }
}
private NetClient _peerClient
{
  get { return _peer as NetClient; }
}
```

Any time you use these two properties, you'd need to null check. For example:

```
public void SendIt()
{
  if(_peerServer == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("_peer is not a NetServer");
  _peerServer.SendToAll(_message); 
}
```

This is not terribly elegant, though. What you should really do is a bit of refactoring. Splitting the class in to separate server/client dependent parts, perhaps with the common functionality in a base class, would be the cleanest option.

Comment: @radarbob I don't understand what you mean. The question states that it isn't really relevant: `[The library]'s not overtly relevant to the issue... I suppose it could easily be any other class or method being referenced here.`

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, I think it's a case of RTFM, or in this case, RTFP, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on wether you want or not your Client to also send a message when you hit `SendIt()`.

If you do, you could do as following:

```
public void SendIt()
{
  if (_peer is NetServer)
    (_peer as NetServer).SendToAll(_message);
  else
    (_peer as NetClient).SendMessage(_message); //as radarbob says it is defined in the Lidgren library, I wouldn't know
}
```

If you don't, you could do this (or follow Damien's suggestion):

```
public void SendIt()
{
  if (!(_peer is NetServer)) throw new InvalidOperationException("SendIt called when we're not the server");
  (_peer as NetServer).SendToAll(_message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The client would never get to SendIt due to logic elsewhere, but I certainly didn't realise you could do what you've done in the if statement. One for the memory bank. That with the direct cast that damien suggested would cover all bases, if I had a client talk back in the future.

Comment: @user2295275 - you can't (directly) do what cassiorgr is showing in their first code block. Just because an `is` test has passed doesn't mean you can call a method from that type. You still need some form of cast.

Comment: @Damien - Yes thanks, I understand that, otherwise my original code would have worked ;-) With your direct cast option tho it would allow me to extend in the future if needs be.

Answer (score -2):

`NetServer` and `NetClient` both inherit from `NetPeer`. `SendToAll()` is not defined in `NetPeer`, so you must use a `SendMessage()` method that is defined in `NetPeer`. That will work for any inheriting classes.

**Edit**
The question says it uses something called the `Lidgren library`. That is always the first place to look for an answer.

Comment: The question is about inheritance and dynamic type usage, not about the Lidgren library.

Comment: Downgrade wars!! Anyway, my answer fits the critera "..without defining it as a NetServer or NetClient...". Why the hell invent stuff when the library provides the needed abstraction? DRY, dude.

Comment: Yes I am using the Lidgren library, but it's not an issue with their library, it's due to the way I was implementing my class and wanting to save on code duplication. I could have put in extra logic and held a reference to NetClient for client based comms and NetServer for server based. The majority of what I'm doing is common apart from The SendToAll being server specific, as you point out.

Comment: Where in `Lidgren library` does it help resolve whether `_peer` is `NetServer` or `NetClient`? I think you should elaborate this. IMHO, I think the issue is simple RTTI testing (`as`, `is`)

Comment: @code4life & radarbob - The Lidgren library isn't the problem, it's a red herring. I could just have two code paths with separate references for NetClient and NetServer and I wouldn't have this issue at all. I was trying to save on code and thought that there must be a way of resolving this, I just didn't know it myself. I shall certainly think twice before posting any questions on here in the future. I've updated the OP with the way I resolved it.

Comment: Don't let this put you off, most people want to help. Unfortunately a minority are quite arrogant and patronising about it.

Comment: I plead insanity. Temporary insanity I think.